# Analytic functions on a disk attaining the maximum of absolute value at $0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all functions $f$ which are analytic in the region $|z|\le 1$ and are such that $f(0)=3$ and $|f(z)|\le 3$ for all z such that $|z|<1$.

How to do this? I know the maximum principle, which says that the maximum value of $|f(z)|$ is attained on $|z|=1 $.

Comment: Have you read on The Maximum Principle?

Comment: Yes... I  have read the maximum principle

Comment: what is the maximum value of $|f(z)|$ on the closed set $|z|\le 1$?

Comment: If I am not mistaken the max value of |f(z)| is attained on |z|=1

Comment: There is more to the story; the maximum of $|f|$ is attained __only__ on the boundary, unless $f$ is constant.

Comment: Also, this is your $25$th question on the site, and you still don't [format them properly](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe due to the maximum modulus Theorem the answer is just f(z)=3 ....since the maximum is not attained on the boundary it must be a constant........

Comment: You can confirm your belief by looking at the comments left 2 days ago.

Comment: Are you saying that my answer is incorrect???